# How to find out what blocks are added by a plugin

Tags: plugins, functions, hooks, block-editor

I am creating a plugin, which adds a number of blocks defined by JS/PHP as per Gutenberg documentation. I want to display these block names on an admin page.

Is there a hook or function I can use which will let me know which blocks are being defined in my plugin from the `register_block_type` function, or will I have to create list and update it manually?

I am currently looping through the below and looking for my `my-block/`in the list and then displaying, is there a better or more accurate way?

```
$block_types = WP_Block_Type_Registry::get_instance()->get_all_registered();
```